# What is the difference between 'come' and 'go' when they use figuratively?

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between 'come' and 'go' when they use figuratively?
For example -

> 1) Prices come down. Prices go down.
>
> 2) Prices come up. Prices go up.

I don't ask about direction what is literally. I mean transition generally. 
Ok. Explain my example about prices.

Comment: "the more examples you give, the better"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Coming up, Gone up and Come, Go](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31421/difference-between-coming-up-gone-up-and-come-go)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, come and go are usually related to some baseline reference. Go means it is moving further away from that reference while come means it is moving towards the reference, just like with directions.

With the example of prices: A reference price you are talking about might be the price of coffee right now. In the future, prices can "go up" and increase, or "go down" and decrease. In both cases the price of coffee is moving away from the current price.

Once the price of coffee "goes up," it can then "come down," meaning the price lowers towards the reference price. The opposite can happen, where it "goes down" and then "comes up".

This baseline reference price can be many different things: the current price, a desired price, or a price at some time in the past are all references.

Comment: For me not enough clear in general usage. 'Price' is just one sample. As I understand if we speak about something new occurs (when things are new) we use ‘go’ when something returns (something happens again) we use ‘come’. Am I right? Could you give more references and situations.